# Codeigniter insert_batch giving error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter's **$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data); ** but it is giving me error as :

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given

Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php

Line Number: 1113
```

my controller code is (just a part of it):

```
foreach ($arrAllergy as $allergy) {
            $allergyData[] = array(
                "user_id" => $userid,
                "allergy_name" => $allergy
            );

        }
        $this->register_model->addAllergy($allergyData);
```

model:

```
public function addAllergy($decoded_data) {

  $this->db->insert_batch('allergies', $decoded_data);
}
```

I have searched a lot for this error but didn't found any solution. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Would be good if you could post your solution for this, if you got it solved.

Answer (score 1):

`insert_batch` requires

key => value pairs where the

key is the column name of the database

and the value is the value

your `array` must be formatted like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [column1] => value
            [column2] => value
            [column3] => value
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [column1] => value
        [column2] => value
        [column3] => value
    )
```

)

`print_r` your array ,what it looks like..

Comment: @user2936213 how about you dump it. and lets have a look? what CI version are you using?

Comment: I am using Codeigniter 1.0